# .NET MAUI javascript file in wwwroot doesnt get copied to wwwroot in the build

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui

I have a .NET MAUI app that's been working great, I have some Javascript actions happening in one of my Javascript files in `wwwroot/js/`, but I did a pretty big refactoring to my C# code and now I cannot manage to get my Javascript files to get copied to the root directory of my build project.

It has worked before and I have tested previous commits before the refactor and it works flawless. But I want to know why it doesn't get copied and my changes should absolutely not affect the `.csproj` or anything close to it in a way that it should skip the `/js` directory.

My Javascript file has the "Build Action" set to "Content" and "Do not copy", I have tried "Copy if never" and "Copy always" but no difference. I have tried to compare the `.js` files to the equivalent `.css` files in the `/css` directory, and they look identical.

What more information do you need to know to be able to help me? :)

Thanks in advance and apologies for the lack of information provided, I don't really know what to send.

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem!

So if the javascript file has a syntax error it wont be included in the wwwroot build output! Worked flawless now!

Comment: Glad to see that you've solved it! You can add more details to your post and check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it will be helpful for those people who are facing the same issue.